# How to stop agent leaving queue when delay + GoTo blocks size = 6 in AnyLogic

Tags: simulation, anylogic

i am using queue before the delay block. The delay block capacity is 6. That is great.

But when I use GoTo block I have to make sure the agent only enter in GoTo block when delay.size < 6.

[image]

If i use wait block instead of queue then i can free on call function and that will solve my problem but **I wana to use queue**.

So how to stop agents leaving queue when delay + GoTo blocks size = 6 in AnyLogic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You put a `Hold` block between the queue and the ped block. You manage it such that it only opens when the queue size < 6. As soon as an agent enters the queue block and its size is now 7 or larger, you close the hold block.

However, logically you will never have agents leaving the queue ever again because they cannot "drain" elsewhere, so you probably need to tune the logic a bit.

But a "Hold" block is your friend here